# Arrays values change not working properly

Tags: c, arrays

I'm doing a long exercise and there is a point where I want to switch values of an array taking into account the values of another one:

EXAMPLE:

Array 1->int segments[segments_Count]. In this example it will be segments [7] = {4,2,3,4,5,6,3}

Array 2->int wall_flag[segments_Count]. In this example it will be wall_flag [7] = {1,0,1,0,0,0,1}

Basically what I want to do is to change values of Array 1 following this rule: from position 0 to 6, if the value of array 2 is 0, then the value of array 1 in the same position is changed to 0.

So the output would look like this: 4,0,3,0,0,0,3

This is the for loop I used trying to get that output:

```
for(i=0;i<segments_Count;i++){
        if(wall_flag[i]==0){
        segments[i]=wall_flag[i];
        }
}
```

The way I read this is: for i that goes from 0 to 6, considering a wall_flag value and a segment value  that are in the same position i of their respective arrays, if wall_flag is equal to 0 then the value of segment goes to 0.

The problem is the output I get is 0000000 and I don't understand why in the loop all the value of array 1 got changed even if there is a clear if condition.

I made sure to check all values of array1,array2 and output to check if I made mistakes in the prior code with a simple printf for loop but the values are exactly the same as I wrote in the example.

```
for(i=0;i<segments_Count;i++){
        printf("%d", segments[i]);
    }
```

Any idea on what is the problem?

Comment: Do try and make your examples more complete. Having snippets of code here and there in your question only serves to frustrate people trying to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why not just `segments[i] = wall_flag[i] ? segments[i] : 0`?

Comment: maybe you have an extra semicolon in your real code? `if(wall_flag[i]==0);{`

Comment: It simply should be `if(wall_flag[i]==0) segments[i] = 0;`

Comment: After spending way too much time reassembling the code from the bits and pieces here [I could not reproduce the problem](https://onlinegdb.com/SyS-tzZwU).

Comment: The problem lies elsewhere in your code. Show the whole thing.

Comment: @Eraklon@tadman tadman code was exactly the answer to my question and in his case it didn't give the error. I couldn't think the mistake was elsewhere in the code because when I was checking  the values stored in the arrays with a printf loop, they were all correct. After checking line x line the whole code multiple times I found a hidden  mistake and finally found the solution. Pretty much in one of the many for loop I had to start from i=1 instead of i=0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tadman posted above in the comment, here is the solution to the problem:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define segments_Count 7

int main() {
  int segments[segments_Count] = {4,2,3,4,5,6,3};
  int wall_flag[segments_Count] = {1,0,1,0,0,0,1};

  for(int i=0;i<segments_Count;i++){
    if(wall_flag[i]==0){
      segments[i]=wall_flag[i];
    }
  }

  for(int i=0;i<segments_Count;i++) {
    printf("%d", segments[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```